# didChangeAuthorizationStatus not called after clicking Allow

Tags: ios, swift, cllocationmanager

This is my code for implementing google map and `CLLocationManager`:

```
class MapViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var MapView: GMSMapView!
    var locationmanager = CLLocationManager()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        locationmanager.delegate = self
        locationmanager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }
}
extension MapViewController: CLLocationManagerDelegate {
    private func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didChangeAuthorizationStatus status: CLAuthorizationStatus) {
     print("didChangeAuthorizationStatus")
     if status == .authorizedWhenInUse {
            locationmanager.startUpdatingLocation()
            MapView.isMyLocationEnabled = true
            MapView.settings.myLocationButton = true
        }
    }

    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
        print("didUpdateLocations")
        if let location = locations.first {
            MapView.camera = GMSCameraPosition(target: location.coordinate, zoom: 15, bearing: 0, viewingAngle: 0)
            locationmanager.stopUpdatingLocation()
        }
    }
}
```

after clicking on Allow or Not Allow `didChangeAuthorizationStatus` never called

Comment: Not really versed in Swift (I'm more of an Objective-C guy), but isn't the `private` qualifier ill-advised here?

Comment: @jcaron Absolutely. Private methods aren't exposed to the Objective-C and hence not to Core Location. It's an optional method so the compiler won't complain (although it should IMO).

Comment: @Amir_P Done. Thanks =)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you are on Swift 3 the whole signature of this method is not correct.

This is what you need:

```
func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didChangeAuthorization status: CLAuthorizationStatus) { 
    //your code 
}
```

Comment: these things should be detected by the compiler if its declared inside an extension

Comment: @Jarryd unfortunately Xcode compiler's not perfect. Things may have changed since this question was posted (half a year ago)

Comment: I was implementing a location manager the other day and compiler complained about marking the function private in the extension. The function would only be called once for some reason. Anyway, this fixed it, thanks!

Comment: I would like to say something! I can not say here.